# Hero Card not showing in Bot framework's emulator

Tags: c#, .net, bots, botframework

I'm new to Bot Framework, I'm using C# to code a simple bot that should return a sample Hero Card as a reply. The problem is that the Hero Card is not showing up in the Bot Framework Channel Emulator. Here's the code:

```
    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> arg)
    {
        var referenceMessage = await arg as IMessageActivity;
        var msg = (Activity)context.MakeMessage();
        Activity replyToConversation = msg.CreateReply($"Buscando resultados para {referenceMessage.Text}");
        replyToConversation.Recipient = msg.From;
        replyToConversation.Type = "message";
        replyToConversation.ReplyToId = referenceMessage.Id;
        replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = "carousel";
        replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        List<CardImage> CardImages = new List<CardImage>();
        CardImages.Add(new CardImage()
        {
            Url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/BMW-Z4_diagonal_front_at_IAA_2005.jpg/243px-BMW-Z4_diagonal_front_at_IAA_2005.jpg"
        });

        CardAction btnWebsite = new CardAction()
        {
            Type = "openUrl",
            Title = "Open",
            Value = "http://bmw.com"
        };

        HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = $"{referenceMessage.Text}",
            Subtitle = $"Resultados de busqueda para {referenceMessage.Text}",
            Images = CardImages,
            Tap = btnWebsite
        };

        var attachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
        replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);

        //var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(msg.ServiceUrl));
        //var reply = connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(replyToConversation);
    }
```

As you can see, I've been trying with both context and connector but the card doesn't show up.I've debugged the application and I can see the input information is being properly captured

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sometimes the problem come from the url of the image. Change the image url to this "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/archive/a/a9/20151112035044!Banyan_Tree_(_Shiv_Bajrang_Dham_Kishunpur).jpeg". if it works, let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post your possible solutions.

*If your function is in some IDialog class, and if you are expecting some result should look like this :

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
```

*Second solution (if i were you, i would use this) is to create a message from current context. So your code should be :

```
 public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> arg)
    {

        var replyToConversation= context.MakeMessage();

        replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = "carousel";
        replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        List<CardImage> CardImages = new List<CardImage>();
        CardImages.Add(new CardImage()
        {
            Url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/BMW-Z4_diagonal_front_at_IAA_2005.jpg/243px-BMW-Z4_diagonal_front_at_IAA_2005.jpg"
        });

        CardAction btnWebsite = new CardAction()
        {
            Type = "openUrl",
            Title = "Open",
            Value = "http://bmw.com"
        };

        HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = $"{referenceMessage.Text}",
            Subtitle = $"Resultados de busqueda para {referenceMessage.Text}",
            Images = CardImages,
            Tap = btnWebsite
        };

        var attachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
        replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
    }
```

Note :

Instead of

```
replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = "carousel",
```

use

```
replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout =  AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you so much for your answer, it worked great and helped me simplify my code. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)